# How can I define a new value to be regressed in Tensorflow Object Detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I'm trying to create a network that does face-detection and also shows a persons age.  displaying age is a regression problem.
Would adding a new parameter to the normal detection label suffice?
I mean currently this is what we do for a simple detection task :

```
filename,width,height,class,xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax
resized_pic_0317.jpg,410,256,man,2,2,406,252
```

Would this be OK? :

```
filename,width,height,class,xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax,age
resized_pic_0317.jpg,410,256,man,2,2,406,252,58
```

if not, what would be the right sequence of actions to do?

Comment: No it would not. The models in the object detection API are made to address the specific problem of detecting some objects on an image, and giving their classes. They are architectured to do so, and in particular are not just a regression on `xmin`, `xmax`, etc. If you add a parameter, it will at best ignore it, at worst confuse `age` with `ymax` (or sthg like that), and in-between just crash...

Comment: You'll have to do a bit more work than that, probably you'll have to load the object detection graph, and add yourself a new regression task on top of the second-stage features (and doing this may be different depending on the model you're using)...

If your dataset only has faces, you could still use the `class` as the `age` parameter, but unfortunately it would give you a classification instead of a regression.

Comment: Thanks alot. so basically the model aside, altering tensorflow OBD API is a hard task. by the way where can I find the actuall model definition for the pretrained model that are available for object detetcion? such as `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017`.

Comment: Yes that's the idea unfortunately. You'll find the meta architectures of FRCNN, RFCN and SSD here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/meta_architectures; the files that link those meta archs to the underlying models (e.g. mobileNet) here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/models/; and the definitions of the underlying models in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim/nets

Comment: Thank you very much . I really appreciate it